# How to follow only specific issues on Github, instead of watching an entire project?

Tags: github, github-issues

Is it possible to follow only specific issues on Github (instead of watching an entire project)? I'd like to get notifications by email when one specific issue changed (pull, state-change, new comments). Is this possible at all?

Comment: If you're on a closing-frenzy have a go at the 900+ questions about Github. All questions (including this) at least tangentially related to Programming imo.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions

Comment: @Andrew. So I take it you agree.

Comment: The Vogons have been at it again.

Comment: See also [Custom thread subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613419/6309) since May 2019.

Comment: why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

As per pennstatephil's comment below, there's a <kbd>SUBSCRIBE</kbd> on the right pane at the bottom:

[image: github screen capture]

Comment: Ha! not sure why I never spotted that, thanks :)

Comment: Looks like they've changed it to a "subscribe" button

Comment: Is it possible to search or list only watched / subscribed issues for a given project?

Comment: It looks like its a slider on/off switch now.  Thanks, I didn't notice it before.