# Does Github send a notification when an issue comment is edited?

Tags: github

For the people who have configured to receive notifications when a comment is posted to an issue in a Github repo: do they also get sent another notification if that comment is edited?

Comment: [Custom thread subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613419/6309) since May 2019 is getting closer, but not yet at the level of a comment modification.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, you do not get a notification if a comment, issue title, or description is edited or even deleted. This can get very confusing if you are answering via email and quote non-existent text.

There is an [issue requesting this feature](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/310) but it has been open for ~2 years without activity. Maybe giving that proposal a thumbs up could help. Unfortunately, no one will be notified of that reactions either...

Comment: Note that https://github.com/isaacs/github is not the actual repository for the GitHub platform; it's just a list of wishes.

Comment: @Arjan Despite that, GitHub is known to use it.

Comment: I actually prefer it that way because I'll often make multiple edits on a post (fixes and rewordings before anybody else has even read it), and I wouldn't want to spam them with a bunch of incremental emails .

Answer (score 13):

Per my experiments, if edit a comment to add a `@mention`, the mentioned user **will** receive the notification, **but only once**, regardless of how many edits are done afterward and whether they are `@mentioned` or not.

Also, quoting a user's reply without `@mention` them **won't** notify them if they are not subscribed to the issue.

Another detail is that if you're `@mentioned` in an issue, you're subscribed to that issue automatically.

GitHub Discussions notification works the same as mentioned above.

If you're subscribed to an issue or a discussion, you'll receive notifications for all new comments and replies for that issue or discussion.

When editing an issue's title, the previous titles will be shown as crossed out on the page, but when editing a discussion's title, the previous titles won't be shown.