# How can I see all the issues I'm watching on Github?

Tags: github

Github has a great feature where you can "watch" an issue. This is handy for getting notifications about progress on that issue.

However, sometimes you want to find the status of an issue you know you've flagged to watch, but can't remember what it was. This is particularly interesting, imho, for projects that are not your own projects. E.g. watching a bug in a library that your project uses but you don't contribute to frequently.

*What I tried*: Note that this is different from [watching a repo](https://github.com/watching). I tried searching github help (for "watch issue" and "subscribe issue" with no luck. I read the [Unsubscribing from Conversations](https://help.github.com/articles/unsubscribing-from-conversations) with some hope, but it didn't quite apply. While looking at the issues for the repository that I (think! I) subscribed to, I tried the various search criteria dropdowns with no luck. Last but not least, I read [how to subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140564/how-to-follow-only-specific-issues-on-github-instead-of-watching-an-entire-proj) here at SO in case it mentioned how to see the subscribed list.

*To those who might flag this as not being about programming, I can only ask for a better place to put this? As Github is a commonly used programming tool, I view this as highly relevant.*

Comment: Yeah sometimes I want to share with others the issues I am following for various frameworks, only to find that it is impossible. This will affect how certain tasks can be handed over.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can see all the GitHub issues you are currently subscribed to at https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions

You can navigate to this page from any page by clicking the notification/bell icon on the top right and then selecting "Manage notifications" > "Subscriptions" from the left menu panel.

Comment: Is it possible to search for all issues I have subscribed to inside a Repo's issue section?

Answer (score 62):

Github does not have any option to list all the watched issues.

Marking labels on such issues also does not solve the purpose.

But github sends notification whenever there is any change in the issue. So you can check all the notification at a single place https://github.com/notifications

By default, this will show unread notifications (also indicated by a mailbox with a number in the top right corner). From that page you can choose "All Notifications", or https://github.com/notifications?all=1 to see all the issues being watched *that have had at least one update since you subscribed to it*.

Comment: Thanks! It seems they added this recently. I noticed it a couple of days ago but hadn't checked it out properly until now.

Comment: **Correction:** Saying "to see all the issues being watched" is not true. It is actually "to see all the issues being watched that have had at least one update since you subscribed to it". :(

Comment: There is an inofficial way to vote for that feature, which might or might not make a difference to get that implemented here: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/283

Comment: The "All Notifications" section only shows you your read notifications for a period of 1 week after you read it.

Comment: not being able to see and manage the issues you've subscribed to seems wonky, hope GH adds this ability, otherwise its just a time bomb you're hoping will go off so you can find what you're looking for

Comment: Now we can just go to https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions — as apaatsio answered below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55781931/3005607

Answer (score 46):

According to the [GitHub API v3 documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues)<sup>1</sup>, there is a way to list subscribed issues in owned repositories, member repositories, and organization repositories. However, it does **not** list subscribed issues from any arbitrary repository in which you are not involved.

On Unix you can access the API like this (just enter your GitHub password when propmted):

```
curl --user "MyUserName" https://api.github.com/issues?filter=subscribed

Output:
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner1/repoA/issues/3",
    "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/owner1/repoA",
...etc...
```

Or use this command to format the output as a list of links to the issues:

```
curl --user "MyUserName" https://api.github.com/issues?filter=subscribed | \
    grep '"url"' | grep -o 'https://api.github.com/repos/.*/issues/[0-9]*' | \
    sed 's#https://api.github.com/repos/#https://github.com/#'

Output:
https://github.com/owner1/repoA/issues/3
https://github.com/owner1/repoB/issues/14
https://github.com/owner2/repoC/issues/1
```

<sup>1</sup> Since my edit to [the first answer mentioning the GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283682/1221661) was rejected, I'm adding the examples here.

---

> The following method **does not work** for **subscribe-only** issues.

As a workaround you can enter this into the search box, either on https://github.com/, or on https://github.com/issues/

```
is:open is:issue involves:YourUserName
```

This will show you all issues in which you are involved in some way, but not issues you are only subscribed to. The [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-within-an-issue-or-pull-request) states:

> The `involves` qualifier is just a logical OR between the `author`, `assignee`, `mentions` and `commenter` qualifiers for the same user.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem for me! Besides, there is Advanced search that can help filter the search results: https://github.com/search/advanced?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+involves%3AYourUserName&ref=searchresults&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: `involves:username` does not work for subscribed-only issues for me, also here https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-a-user-thats-involved-within-an-issue-or-pull-request it says nothing about subscribed.

Comment: @zormit That is one of the reasons why so many people comment with +1's

Comment: @zormit: You are right, it doesn't work, though I believe it did when I wrote this answer. Or I was just mistaken. Anyways, I don't understand why this answer is *still* collecting upvotes. Maybe I should delete it?

Comment: It's collecting upvotes because in the absence of a way to find all issues you're subscribed to, this at least helps people find all issues they've commented on.  ...which is something I didn't know how to do until I found this answer.  Face it man....you're the closest thing people can find on Google :)

Comment: The upvote indicates "This answer is useful." I found this answer useful, since I used this to find something I *had* commented on that I couldn't find before. Hence, I upvote :).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all the issues for a certain project that you have been part of i.e, interacted with that issue in any way. Do this;

In the search of Github issues do this.

```
is:issue commenter:<username here>
```

This will list all the issues that you are watching.

Comment: does `commenter` really catch watched issues that I didn't leave a comment on?

Comment: no it doesn't. But this might help https://github.com/rugk/otherfiles/wiki/GitHub-search-terms-cheat-sheet :)

Comment: There is also `involves:<username here>` a good option. It will give you all the issues you are involved in preferably the ones you are watching as well.

Comment: Neither `commenter` nor `involves` includes subscribed issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can fetch this information via Github API

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#parameters

> GET /orgs/:org/issues

```
Parameters
Name    Type    Description
filter  string  Indicates which sorts of issues to return. Can be one of:
* assigned: Issues assigned to you
* created: Issues created by you
* mentioned: Issues mentioning you
* subscribed: Issues you're subscribed to updates for
* all: All issues the authenticated user can see, regardless of participation or creation
Default: assigned
```

Comment: This only seems to work for issues in repositories which you own, which you are a member of, or which are owned by your organization. As written on https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues : "List all issues assigned to the authenticated user across all visible repositories including owned repositories, member repositories, and organization repositories. You can use the filter query parameter to fetch issues that are not necessarily assigned to you."